# Showcaseview in landscape orientation, content text overflows

Tags: android, showcaseview

I'm using the showcaseview library in my Android app to display a first time tutorial to new users. So far it's been fairly straightforward to get going; I have a number of different viewpager tabs at the top of the page that are getting consecutively showcased, which is great ... in portrait mode.

However when the device is rotated, or I start my app in landscape orientation, the title and content text that I have for my showcase is displayed at the bottom of the screen and it eventually overflows off the screen. The showcase text content isn't more than a sentence and I can't think I'm the first person to have this problem so I'm wondering if any one else has come across this and how they solved it?

I was thinking that since showcaseview calculates the best position for the text based on free canvas space that I could probably move my content up by reducing the radius of the showcase cirlce, although I have yet to try this.

Also, I don't want to restrict users by locking the orientation to portrait mode during the tutorial.

EDIT: I've temporarily settled for locking the screen to portrait orientation if I deem the height and width of the target device to be too small. It's not my ideal solution so I'm still keen to hear the thoughts of any showcaseview users out there.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that you're using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize` for your Activity, which means you need to redraw the ShowcaseView in `onConfigurationChanged`.